# Is there any way to export MySQL Workbench 8 connections by shell commands?

Tags: backup, shell, mysql-workbench, database-administration

I need to add some shell commands to my backup script to take a backup of defined MySQL connections in the Workbench.

MySQL workbench allows this in its GUI: menu bar > Tools > Configuration > Backup Connections.

I tried searching this problem but the results was frustrating!

** Thanks in advance **

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you already have tried something please post it, that way it is way less work for us than if we had to write a complete script. Doing so your question is more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: By default, the connection profiles are stored in a file called WbProfiles.xml in the configuration directory. Source: [How to export / import connections in SQL Workbench?](https://groups.google.com/g/sql-workbench/c/jowehjDyHws)

Comment: [MySQL :: MySQL Administrator :: D How Connections Are Stored](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/administrator/en/mysql-gui-appendix-store-connections.html)

Answer (score 3):

After doing the above "Backup Connections", you will find the
connections in the file `connections.xml`.

According to chapter
[3.3 MySQL Workbench Settings and Log Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html),
this file is found at folder:

Windows:

```
%AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\
```

Linux:

```
~/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml
```

However, I'm not sure if that file can be imported, or perhaps just
be simply copied to the target computer.

Comment: I am using ubuntu and the connections file is ~/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml; I hope replacing this file do the job.

Comment: I think connections.xml should be the main non-volatile location of the connections, independent of performing a backup.